# Base change and fppf sheafification

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:S'\to S$ be a morphism of schemes, $F$ a presheaf on the category (Sch/S) of $S$-schemes, and denote by $F^{(fppf)}$ the fppf sheafification of $F$.

Is there an isomorphism $(f^*F)^{(fppf)}\cong f^*(F^{(fppf)})$ of (fppf) sheaves on (Sch/S')?

If not, under what assumptions does this hold?

I am mainly interested in the case when $F=h_X/G$ is the presheaf on (Sch/S) obtained by taking the quotient of the functor of points $h_X$ of a quasi-projective $S$-scheme $X$ by a non-free action of a constant finite group $G$. If here the action of $G$ on $X$ would be free, then the answer to my question would be yes in this special case.

Comment: I thought that this is true for every map of sites.

Comment: The natural map from the right to the left $f^*(F^{\rm{fppf}}) \to (f^*F)^{\rm{fppf}}$ is defined as adjoint to the map on fppf-sheafifications induced by $F\rightarrow f_*(f^*F)$. The map from left to right is defined by the universal property of sheafification applied to the map $f^*F\to f^*(F^{\rm{fppf}})$ (caveat: you might intend for $f^*$ on the left to have different meaning from the one on the right, but the distinction is wiped out by sheafifying). Then one checks in various ways that these are inverse to each other.  As Piotr Achinger notes, the argument is of a rather formal nature.

Comment: Beware however that if $F = h_Y$ is the functor of points of an $S$-scheme $Y$, then $f^*F$ is generally *not* the same thing as $h_{Y \times_S S'}$ when $f$ isn't flat and locally finitely presented.  (One sees a version of the same phenomenon more concretely using the etale topology when $f$ is not etale and $Y$ is not $S$-etale.)

Comment: What I had in mind is even more formal: draw a square of four categories of sheaves/presheaves on $S$/$S'$ and four adjunctions: forgetful functor and sheafification on $S$ and $S'$, $f^*$ and $f_*$ on sheaves and presheaves. The square with forgetting and $f_*$ naturally commutes, so the square with sheafifying and $f^*$ does so as well. (I hope this explanation is clear without a diagram)

Comment: @PiotrAchinger: I agree, but just as a matter of taste I prefer to directly describe maps whenever possible (not just appeal to abstract adjunctions, etc.), even though it is typically just a mechanical process to do so.